# Ruby on Heroku Memcache error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, heroku

To preface I am a Ruby newbie.

When I try to run my app on Heroku with memcache I get the following error:

/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/cache.rb:65:in `rescue in lookup_store': Could not find cache store adapter for memcached_store (no such file to load -- active_support/cache/memcached_store) (RuntimeError)

Does anyone know what this means? I added the heroku addon for memcache.

Comment: do you have `gem 'dalli' #memcached`  in your gem file?

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile? And why are you using `memcache_store` instead of `dalli_store`?

Comment: I tried both and got this same error so that's why I went to memcache. Ill try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [these instructions](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache#rails_setup) to install `dalli` client to use Memcached.